# urlPatterns after /* is not is not working in servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm getting below error on tomcat

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

When I changed `urlPattern = "/display"` Its working fine

**Servlet Code:**

```
@WebServlet(name = "DisplayView", urlPatterns = "/display/*")
public class DisplayView extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String landingPage = "WEB-INF/jsps/display.jsp";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(landingPage).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.skr.mediaviewer.views.DisplayView.doGet(DisplayView.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    .
    .
    SAME LINES AGAIN AND AGAIN
    .
    .
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.skr.mediaviewer.views.DisplayView.doGet(DisplayView.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Root Cause**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    .
    .
    SAME LINES AGAIN AND AGAIN
    .
    .
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    com.skr.mediaviewer.views.DisplayView.doGet(DisplayView.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    .
    .
    SAME LINES AGAIN AND AGAIN
    .
    .
    com.skr.mediaviewer.views.DisplayView.doGet(DisplayView.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Very good.  It looks like you've coded yourself up a little servlet request handler that goes into an infinite recursion  ;)

Comment: When I changed `urlPatterns = "/display"` Its working fine

Comment: The fact is - whatever you're doing - you seem to be causing an infinite recursion.  SUGGESTION: Put a breakpoint at the start of your doGet(), and reproduce the problem under the debugger.  Please post back what you find :)

Comment: I put the break point and its keep getting executed again and again..
When I hit this url `http://localhost:8080/MediaViewer/display/tag/123` I got below response from `request.getPathInfo()`
`/tag/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/WEB-INF/jsps/display.jsp`